# Annotate a queryset by a values queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to annotate a count of objects to a queryset, which I know how to do, but I want the objects counted to have their own filtering.

This works well;

```
first_model_qs = FirstModel.objects.filter(do a bunch of filtering)
grouped_values_qs = first_model_qs.values('second_model').annotate(Count('pk'))
```

So I now have a nice queryset with all the `first_model` counts grouped by `second_model` ids. Awesome.

What I'd like to do now is something like;

```
secound_model_qs = SecondModel.objects.annotate(first_model_count = grouped_values_qs)
```

And then be able to say `secound_model_qs.first().first_model_count`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do it with a [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) and more specifically by [Using aggregates within a Subquery expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#using-aggregates-within-a-subquery-expression)

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Count

first_model_query = (FirstModel.objects
    # Do the filtering
    .filter(second_model=OuterRef('pk'))
    # add grouping
    .values('second_model')
    # do the aggregation
    .annotate(cnt=Count('pk'))
    # now return only a single column
    .values('cnt')
)

secound_model_qs = SecondModel.objects.annotate(
    first_model_count=Subquery(first_model_query)
)
```